Finite difference method for shallow water equations
Problem
In the book "Modern Fortran", the 1D shallow water equations
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + u \cdot \nabla u = -g \nabla h,  \\
&\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = - \nabla \cdot (u(H + h)),  
\end{align}
appear to be discretized incorrectly using the finite difference method. The discretization for the flow velocity in the book is
\begin{equation}
u^{t+1} = u^{t} - \frac{u^{t} \cdot \nabla u^{t} + g \nabla h^{t}}{\Delta x \Delta t},
\end{equation}
however, when I work out the discretization, I get
\begin{equation}
u^{t+1} = u^{t} - (u^{t} \cdot \nabla u^{t} + g \nabla h^{t}) \Delta t.
\end{equation}
Have I made an error in my discretization or is the book incorrect?
Context and Attempt
I am following the book "Modern Fortran", and the 1D shallow water equations are defined as follows:
\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + u \cdot \nabla u = -g \nabla h,   \\
&\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = - \nabla \cdot (u(H + h)),  
\end{align}
where $u$ is the flow velocity such that $u := u(x, t)$, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration, $h$ is the watter elevation, $H$ is the unperturbed water depth, and $t$ is time.
The book's accompanying code implementing these equations is here, and it defines the finite difference as
time_loop: do n = 1, num_time_steps

    ! compute u at next time step
    u = u - (u * diff(u) + g * diff(h)) / dx * dt

    ! compute h at next time step
    h = h - diff(u * (hmean + h)) / dx * dt

end do time_loop

pure function diff(x) result(dx) ! called 'diff_centered' in the code base 
  ! Returns a 2nd order centered difference of a 1-d array,
  ! with periodic boundary condition.
  real(real32), intent(in) :: x(:)
  real(real32) :: dx(size(x))
  integer(int32) :: im
  im = size(x)
  dx(1) = x(2) - x(im)
  dx(im) = x(1) - x(im-1)
  dx(2:im-1) = x(3:im) - x(1:im-2)
  dx = 0.5 * dx
end function diff_centered

which, looking at the flow velocity first, is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
u^{t+1} = u^{t} - \frac{u^{t} \cdot \nabla u^{t} + g \nabla h^{t}}{\Delta x \Delta t}. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
This, however, does not seem to be the correct discretization. Below is my approach to the forward time discretization.
\begin{align}
\frac{u^{t+1} - u^{t}}{\Delta t} + u^{t} \cdot \nabla u^{t} &= -g \nabla h^{t}, \\
\frac{u^{t+1} - u^{t}}{\Delta t} &= -(u^{t} \cdot \nabla u^{t}  + g \nabla h^{t}), \\
\frac{u^{t+1}}{\Delta t} &= \frac{u^{t}}{\Delta t} -(u^{t} \cdot \nabla u^{t}  + g \nabla h^{t}), \\
u^{t+1} &= u^{t} - (u^{t} \cdot \nabla u^{t} + g \nabla h^{t}) \Delta t. \tag{2}
\end{align}
Clearly, equation (1) and equation (2) are not equivalent
\begin{equation}
u^{t} - (u^{t} \cdot \nabla u^{t} + g \nabla h^{t}) \Delta t \neq u^{t} - \frac{u^{t} \cdot \nabla u^{t} + g \nabla h^{t}}{\Delta x \Delta t}
\end{equation}
Note that I do not explicitly show the central space discretization since this is already implemented in the code as
\begin{equation}
\nabla(v) := \frac{v(x + \Delta x) - v(x - \Delta x)}{2 \Delta x}.
\end{equation}

The discretization in the book is certainly wrong since its units don't work out.

I think I see what's going on. I'm not a Fortran guy, so correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like the function diff(x) in the code takes a central difference of the array x without dividing by the mesh size $\Delta x$. Dividing by $\Delta x$ is taken care of explicitly in the time loop. What about the $\Delta t$? The order of operations in Fortran has evaluations of multiplication and division go from left to right. Looking at the stuff in the time loop, it divides by $\Delta x$ and then multiplies (not divides) by $\Delta t$. Thus, in the code your two expressions are equivalent.

You are correct. I think the diff function body confused me because he uses dx there to define an array and also uses dx in the time loop to define the mesh size. Thanks for pointing this out!

The implementation in the book is correct. Per @John Barber's comments, the diff function does not actually use the grid size $\Delta x$ so it is necessary to divide by the grid size in the time loop itself. My confusion arose from the fact that dx is used both in the definition of diff and in the time loop; however, the latter is an array and the former is a scalar.
